# Can someone please explain this c# syntax?

Tags: c#, syntax

I'm having difficulty understanding the nested parenthesis in this statement. Can someone explain? I understand that `HttpWebRequest` class inherits the `WebRequest` class according to the definition but I'm not understanding why this is written this way and why request isn't created as an instance of `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebRequest`. Tried it but it won't compile. Thanks in advance.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
((HttpWebRequest)request).AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
```

Comment: that is just casting `request` to `HttpWebRequest` which has the `AllowReadStreamBuffering` property.

Comment: it is a `HttpWebRequest` but it is referenceds as a `WebRequest`.

Comment: [Casting and Type Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)

Comment: Look what the [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588(v=vs.110).aspx) returns: `WebRequest`. So either you had to cast it where you calll `Create` or one line after where you use `AllowReadStreamBuffering`.

Comment: I'm not sure if SO is the best place to ask for an explanation of someone else's code. [ask].  Wishing you well

Comment: You should also use titles which describe your specific question

Answer (score 0):

That is simply casting the request to an HttpWebRequest

Please check out the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Answer (score 0):

WebRequest.Create is probably gonna return different implementations of the same Interface, that´s why it can´t be a constructor and also why you have to do the type cast to actually have full access to the class as opposed to only the methods available threw the interface, if you know what it´s supposed to be when you pass xyz into create. If it´s not that the cast will fail.